# Appending Input type using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending HTML in javascript.

```
var HTML = "<input type='image'  src='../../images/edit_btn.png' onclick='popadmin('http://www.example.com','station',585,971); return false;' style='border-width:0px;margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 0px'>";
```

but it generate this HTML

```
var HTML = <input type="image" src="../../images/edit_btn.png" onclick="popadmin(" http:="" www.example.com','station',585,971);="" return="" false;'="" style="border-width:0px;margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 0px">
```

Why this `popadmin('http://www.example.com'` change to `http:="" www.example.com'` ?
how i can prevent it

Comment: Have you tried to escape like this \/\/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you use wrong quotes, do it dis way:

```
var HTML = "<input type='image'  src='../../images/edit_btn.png' onclick=\"popadmin('http://www.example.com','station',585,971); return false;\" style='border-width:0px;margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 0px'>";
```

Answer (score -2):

should use single quote.

this is a example for "LI" is similar

```
function addLI(id, href, name){
var html = '<li><a id ="'+id+ '" href="' + href + '">' + name+ '</a></li>';
return html;
}
```

Comment: The problem is not using single quotes to delimit attribute values (nothing wrong with that). The problem is using unescaped single quotes in a single-quote-delimted value. See Sergio's answer.

Comment: Ok "is not an error as such," but it's another way to solve the problem.

Comment: No, it isn't. You still need to escape the quotes, no matter if they're single or double quotes.

Comment: @JohnPaulCárdenas Your answer does not really solve the problem. You did not understand the question. The OP is using single quotes inside single quotes without escaping them. `var xyz = 'popadmin('http://www.example.com','station',585,971);'`. What do you think that will produce?